# Financials ACLs status error

Tags: civicontribute

The extention "Financials ACLs" throws an error on the system status page because it is missing CiviContribute. I never installed this extention on purpose and I don't find it inside the extention management. The error says:

```
There is one extension error:
"Financial ACLs" (financialacls) has a missing dependency on "CiviContribute" (civi_contribute)
To resolve any errors, go to Manage Extensions.
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in Civi where the extension gets installed forcefully even though the Contribution extension is enabled or not. You will not be able to see the extension in the extension page but uou can disable the extension by running below SQL

```
UPDATE civicrm_extension 
SET is_active = 0
WHERE full_name = 'financialacls';

TRUNCATE civicrm_cache;
```